# how to create an R package that only contains a dataset?

Tags: r

I am looking for the easiest way to create an R package that only needs to contain a single dataset.

Assume my dataset (say, a `dplyr` dataframe) is written to disk as `.rds` (or lives in the current session). Is there a way to put it into an `R` package without having to install `rtools` and others? Can this be done programmatically?

The idea is that this package would be re-created every time I run some other code. Then I could ship this package-dataset to other programs.

Thanks again!

Comment: yes, a very fundamental one. In a nutshell, when using `sparklyr`, the workers can have access to packages but cannot have access to external data easily. Therefore, if I want to use external data (or statistical models) that are created outside Spark, I need to ship them via packages.

Comment: The [nycflights13](https://github.com/hadley/nycflights13) package is much like this. Check out that github to see how to lay it out. Pretty easy just to set up with `devtools`. Don't need to compile anything. But to make it into a shareable package it does need to have the documentation stuff compiled and packed into a tarball. Depending on OS, you might not need all of rtools to build. But certainly users of your package will not need `rtools`.

Comment: thank you @MrFlick, do you mind explaining the required steps as an asnwer then? by looking at the upvotes in such a short amount of time, there seem to be interest in understanding how to do that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I wrote a data-only package - https://github.com/nfultz/ec2instances.info/blob/master/R/ec2instances.R

In the .onLoad function, you can load data however you like, in my case from querying a website.

Alternatively, you could just use `package.skeleton` to make a empty package. You are supposed to edit the help files, but I just used sed instead:

```
> foo <- iris
> package.skeleton("irispkg", "foo")
Creating directories ...
Creating DESCRIPTION ...
Creating NAMESPACE ...
Creating Read-and-delete-me ...
Saving functions and data ...
Making help files ...
Done.
Further steps are described in './irispkg/Read-and-delete-me'.
> system("sed -i 's/^%%//' irispkg/man/foo.Rd")
> system("R CMD build irispkg")
* checking for file 'irispkg/DESCRIPTION' ... OK
* preparing 'irispkg':
* checking DESCRIPTION meta-information ... OK
* installing the package to process help pages
* saving partial Rd database
* checking for LF line-endings in source and make files and shell scripts
* checking for empty or unneeded directories
* looking to see if a 'data/datalist' file should be added
* building 'irispkg_1.0.tar.gz'

> install.packages("./irispkg_1.0.tar.gz", repos=NULL)
Installing package into '/home/neal/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.4'
(as 'lib' is unspecified)
* installing *source* package 'irispkg' ...
** data
** help
Warning: /tmp/RtmpW8T900/Rbuild8c0136c3b349/irispkg/man/irispkg-package.Rd:27: All text must be in a section
Warning: /tmp/RtmpW8T900/Rbuild8c0136c3b349/irispkg/man/irispkg-package.Rd:28: All text must be in a section
*** installing help indices
** building package indices
** testing if installed package can be loaded
* DONE (irispkg)
```

check that it works:

```
> require(irispkg)
Loading required package: irispkg
> data(foo)
> head(foo)
  Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa
2          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa
3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa
4          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2  setosa
5          5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2  setosa
6          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4  setosa
```

Comment: thanks that is pretty cool. is package.skeleton a base R function? What is the purpose of the two command line calls (`sed` !?)

Comment: The sed command deletes the comment markers from the default help file, without that the package will not build. `R CMD build` is how you build a package from source.

Comment: the sed portion is relevant to the motivation behind http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/code/pkgkitten.html

Comment: Thanks neal that is really cool I am accepting this of course. I think for the sake of proposing a really complete answer, do you know if we can use `devtools` here?

Comment: See also ?devtools::create and ?devtools::build - note that create won't add a data set to the package for you, so you will have to add it some other way (eg save commands or something).

Comment: @NealFultz ah thats annoying indeed... thanks anyways